# How to use case statements in BASH?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Description:

I have code which extracts the time stamping's by matching a key word/sentence of a .log file which is existing in several folders of the form `log_Job_*`.

It calculates time duration's of different processes and write the output to a .CSV file.

What columns I want to have in my .csv:

1. FileName
2. ProcessType

   - Import
   - Validate
3. .
   .
4. MainPartionDuration

Now the problem is, I have 2 types of process under 2. Process Type. So, thought of using case statements here. And did as following:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/manoj/version_2019_logs/

for file in log_Job_*/manoj.log; do

    ProcessType1="$(grep -F 'Running process mpeXbrlImport.xml' "$file" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -c 4-)"
    ProcessType2="$(grep -F 'Running process mpeXbrlValidate.xml' "$file" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -c 4-)"
    ProcessType="$ProcessType1","$ProcessType2"

    case $ProcessType in 
        $ProcessType1)
            #set of commands to get other variaqbles
            Var="$Filename","$ProcessType","$TotalDuration","$Initialization","$MPEProcessDuration","$TotalPartitionDuration","$WaitPartitionDuration","$MainPartionDuration"
            echo $Var >>OutputFile_Import.csv
            ;;
        *)
            #repeat the set of commands and this time save with different variable names 
            Var1="$Filename1","$ProcessType1","$TotalDuration1","$Initialization1","$MPEProcessDuration1","$TotalPartitionDuration1","$WaitPartitionDuration1","$MainPartionDuration1"
            echo $Var1 >>OutputFile_Validate.csv
            ;;
    esac
done
```

With this my plan is to create two separate .CSV files based on the `Processtype` and then concatenate both the files.

**Problem:** The script is getting executed successfully, but at the end it is generating only *one* file i.e. `OutputFile_Validate.csv`

I have verified the script carefully, am not using any variables repeatedly. 
Can someone tell me, what could be the reason for this!!

Comment: @steeldriver What can I use instead of case in this scenario to solve my problem ?

Comment: Could you show us typical `ProcessType1` and `ProcessType2`?

Comment: @Mathieu Yes. XbrlImport.xml and XbrlValidate.xml

Comment: What @steeldriver suggest is more elegant -- But if you need some `if fi` tests inside the `for` loop, you may also use `case esac` -- The issue you are facing seems to be that an expected empty var `ProcessType2` is not empty, and as you concatenate it, the result never matches the `case` condition...

Comment: @cmak.fr it will never match, because of the comma character between the concatenated variables

Comment: @cmak.fr exactly that is why I have used the case esac. Yes, the variable ProcessType2 is not empty. I haven't included the concatenation into the script yet.

Comment: @steeldriver can you please show me, how can I use for instead of case to solve this problem. I didn't quite get the logic exactly here. Ans is it recommendable to write for loop inside another for loop ??

Comment: "Yes, the variable ProcessType2 is not empty. I haven't included the concatenation into the script yet" -- You mean that you dont show us the code causing trouble -- How to help?

Comment: @cmak.fr am showing you the whole code that I have :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, you want to feed import.csv when `ProcessType1` is not empty and validate.csv when `ProcessType2` is not.

You can `test` if the variable is set and not empty with:

```
if [ -n "$VAR" ];
then
    echo "VAR is set\n"
fi
```

---

Your code could looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/manoj/version_2019_logs/

for file in log_Job_*/manoj.log; do

    ProcessType1="$(grep -F 'Running process mpeXbrlImport.xml' "$file" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -c 4-)"
    ProcessType2="$(grep -F 'Running process mpeXbrlValidate.xml' "$file" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -c 4-)"

    if [ -n "$ProcessType1" ];
    then
        #set of commands to get other variaqbles
        Var="$Filename","$ProcessType1","$TotalDuration","$Initialization","$MPEProcessDuration","$TotalPartitionDuration","$WaitPartitionDuration","$MainPartionDuration"
        echo $Var >>OutputFile_Import.csv
    fi
    if [ -n "$ProcessType2" ];
    then
            #repeat the set of commands and this time save with different variable names 
            Var1="$Filename1","$ProcessType2","$TotalDuration1","$Initialization1","$MPEProcessDuration1","$TotalPartitionDuration1","$WaitPartitionDuration1","$MainPartionDuration1"
            echo $Var1 >>OutputFile_Validate.csv
    fi
done
```